# How to resolve the return type of a forwarding reference?

Tags: c++, templates, forward-reference

There is an existing `expected<T,E>` class which provides these `typedefs` and `operators`:

```
value_type = T
operator *(): expected<T,E>& -> value_type&
              const expected<T,E>& -> const value_type&
              expected<T,E>&& -> value_type&&
              const expected<T,E>&& -> const value_type&&
```

Now I'm writing a function like this:

```
template <typename E> 
/*type*/ Unwrap(E&& e)
{
    return e.has_value() ? /*what*/
        : throw e.error();
}
```

what should I put in the comment block?
I've tried `auto&&` and `*e`, it received an `excepted&&` but returned a `value_type&`.
I've also tried `std::forward`, but it even couldn't be compiled.

how should I do?

Comment: I like the concept!  I made a bunch that would "unwrap" a pointer or throw, a unique_ptr or throw, an optional or throw, a shared pointer or throw... this is fun!  (And obviously the variant result-or-error `expected`, as is the intent.)

Comment: @Eljay you can also add a parameter called `exceptionFactory` and code like this:`return e.has_value() ? *std::forward<E>(e) : throw exceptionFactory(e.error());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `decltype(auto)` as the return type:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename E> 
decltype(auto) Unwrap(E&& e) {
  return e.has_value() ? *std::forward<E>(e)
    : throw e.error();
}
```